# execute a MySQL stored procedure from Google app script

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, jdbc, google-apps-script

How can I get my google app script to recognise 'CallableStatement'?

I am trying to execute a stored proc on a MySQL database using Google App Script to insert data from Google Sheets but the script is not recognising the  'CallableStatement" object type.

`var query = '{call InsertBandSong(?,?,?,?,?,?)}';
  CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(query);`

The above triggers an error message every time I go to save the script file.

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40919246/execute-stored-procedure-in-google-apps-script) answer but the solution provided is coded in c#. Appscript uses Javascript doesn't it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40919246/execute-stored-procedure-in-google-apps-script this should explain it.

Comment: [Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#write_to_the_database) is a sample. You should use `prepareCall` instead of `prepareStatement`, but the rest should be more or less the same.

Comment: _"The above triggers an error message every time I go to save the script file."_ What is that error message?